# What is the best way to break up this string in Python?

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I am parsing a text file that looks something like this:

```
a1 a2 a3               b1 b2 b3
a1                     b1 b2
a1 a2                  b1
```

Basically what I want to end up with is each column in its own string. I'm pretty sure there is an obvious answer to this but I think I've been staring at the screen too long....

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A couple of questions, are there ever spaces in the entries (e.g. "a 2") and what actually separates the blocks of columns?

Comment: use csv format for your file and use python csv module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the second time this has happened to me in the last couple of days. I've managed to solve my own problem...

The text layout is effectively fixed - the "second half" of the line always starts at character 31 and so you can simply split at that point and then parse each side individually.

Thanks all for answering!

Comment: hey, solving your own problems is never bad. Try to post a proper answer to your question tough preferably with a code sample so others can benefit

Answer (score 1):

You could [read each line](http://docs.python.org/library/readline.html) and split on more then one space or a tab, wichever is between column 1 and 2